# Копирование таблиц с определенным префиксом в названии

Tags: php, mysql

Контекст php, mysql.
Есть необходимость быстро создавать копии (структуры или полные не важно) таблиц с определенным префиксом (ну например "prefix" в названии таблицы "prefix_table_name") под новым префиксом (например "newprefix_table_name"). Тобиш в системе будет забит префикс исходных таблиц и будет указываться префикс с которым нужно создать копии. Возможно ли этого добиться? В результате как и в примере исходный префикс хорошо бы отрезать заменив на новый (с "prefix_table_name" получив "newprefix_table_name"), с другой стороны это можно сделать потом дополнительным запросом переименования.

Пробовал LIKE всячески использовать для выборки имен таблиц, но не выходит.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В MySQL есть таблица, в которой содержаться имена всех таблиц. Она называется `tables`. Она находиться в БД `information_schema`. Эта база может быть скрыта, будьте внимательны.

Для выбора всех таблиц, содержащихся на сервере (или доступных пользователю, который подключен) можно использовать запрос: `select * from information_schema.tables`. Следовательно, чтобы сделать выбор:

`SELECT * FROM information_schema.tables WHERE TABLE_NAME LIKE '%prefix%';`

Вывод будет содержать таблицы по маске. Но если Вы делаете это из под root, а на сервере содержаться другие таблицы с походим префиксом, то выборка покажет и их. Чтобы этого избежать, добавьте в WHERE `TABLE_SCHEMA = 'db_name'`, где db_name — имя целевой базы данных.

Comment: Нашел таблицу и в ней всё необходимое. Спасибо!